# Registry level counters in Linux accessible from Java

Tags: c#, java, windows, linux, performancecounter

I am looking for counters in Linux systems similar to custom counters in Windows, which could be accessed through C#. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326924%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). My use case is this: I have a process that imports a file from location A to B. This file has some XML records that need to be parsed and loaded into a database. I want to have counters which I can keep incrementing, for example, whenever a new file is received at B, and whenever a record is imported into the database. I want to log these counter values at regular intervals to detect any inconsistencies. I used to do this with custom counters (refer to the link above) when I was using Windows+C#, but how can I do this in Linux+Java ?
Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 2):

Linux doesn't have a registry (thank goodness) I wouldn't suggest you mix application data with your OS. Java has User preferences, but I don't recommended you use it for this type of information.

If you want to record some information, write it to a file, or database e.g. http://java-sources.net/open-source/database-engines A file might be the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

The real win with creating a custom counter in a Windows application is that **you can monitor your application at runtime using the [Windows Performance Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749249.aspx)**.  So in your example you could watch how the number of files received over time changes.

**The "Java way" (i.e. platform independent) of doing something simillar is [JMX](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/mntr-mgmt/javamanagement/).**

By all means write the values to a file or database as Peter suggests.  That will give you a historic view of the stats.  But I strongly recommend you investigate JMX as a way of monitoring your application at runtime analogous to Windows counters.